# UISearchController subclass crash on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

Is there any way to do subclass of UISearchController that works on iOS12?

```
final class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

private let onCancel: () -> Void

init(
    onSelect: @escaping (MKPlacemark) -> Void,
    onCancel: @escaping () -> Void
) {
    self.onCancel = onCancel
    let searchResultsController = SearchResultsController(onSelect: onSelect)
    super.init(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
    obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

Above code works on iOS14 but it crashes on iOS12. Reason is that super.init(searchResultsController) calls self.init(nibName: ...) and this calls again CustomSearchController initializer for init(nibName:...) on CustomSearchController

Answer (score 0):

You should override `init(nibName:bundle)` in addition to the initializer you've already overriden. `init(nibName:bundle:)` is a designated initializer while `init(rootViewController:)` is a convenience initializer (at least below 13 iOS).

Just insert additional snippet in your class:

```
override init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?) {
    onCancel = {}
    super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
}
```

Whereas within your initializer you have to move  `self.onCancel = onCancel` after super init call.

It should work.